# Can't input a string on Element using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, authentication, automation

**Introduction**

I want to automate some process and learn something new along the way. So far my scope is to be able to log into a website. For such thing I use the next code.

**Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO code application logic here

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Users/Jonathan/Desktop/Java/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe");


        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        WebElement element = null;

        driver.get("https://somewebsite.com/");
        //Representa un elemento HTML, interactuar con la pagina

        driver.findElement(By.className("dialog_login_opener")).click();

        WebElement userNameInputField = driver.findElement(By.id("mail_or_login_field"));
        WebElement passwordInputField = driver.findElement(By.name("userData[password]"));

        userNameInputField.sendKeys("email@gmail.com");
        passwordInputField.sendKeys("123456");


        element.submit();

        //element.sendKeys("Hola Google!");

        System.out.print(driver.getTitle());

        Thread.sleep(5);

        driver.quit();  

    }
```

**Problem**

So far I have been able to input the username right. The field used for such thing is:

```
<input type="text" name="userData[login]" tabindex="1" id="mail_or_login_field" class="input mail errtip tooltipstered" required="" placeholder="E-mail or Login">
```

so that explains what i have used before:

```
WebElement userNameInputField = driver.findElement(By.id("mail_or_login_field"));
```

but when it comes to input the password it doesn't do it. Instead throws at me this exception error I can not understand.

**Password field:**

```
<input type="password" name="userData[password]" tabindex="2" class="input pass1 errtip tooltipstered" required="" placeholder="Password">
```

**Exception Error Log**

```
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 72.0.3626.7 (efcef9a3ecda02..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\L...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:55872}, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: ignore, unhandledPromptBehavior: ignore, version: 71.0.3578.98, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: 8e80f9dcea262abb66d7888234704503
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:106)
    at seleniumtest.SeleniumTest.main(SeleniumTest.java:46)
C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\9.0\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\9.0\executor-snippets\run.xml:94: Java returned: 1
```

Comment: `element` appears to be null when you try to call `element.submit()`.

Comment: Try using `By.xpath` or `By.className` rather than `By.name` to find the password field. Then you can use either the relative path to the password field or the class `Pass1`.

Comment: @Jason, the error is before that. At the password sendKeys which by some reason is not sent.

Comment: Have you used a debugger to see what `passwordInputField` is set to before you call `sendKeys`? If not, that would be a good thing to try.

Comment: @Jason, the class name has a weird one and by some reason too. Doesn't work, next thing might be the xpath. '(class="input pass1 errtip tooltipstered")'

Comment: Try `By.className('pass1')`.

Comment: @Jason, pass1 doesn't work either. I'm currently debugging and can't see the sendKey input. I only see ´[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (1c5f4307bd52e26a723e643eeecc9776)] -> name: userData[login]´ but no email@gmail.com

Comment: If the xpath is //*[@id="old"]/form/label[2]/input how do I input it into the By.xpath()?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML and error stack trace

Comment: @WhiteGlove regarding the xpath you used in the comment above..., it is not robust. try something like in my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the locator to `By.xpath` like this:

```
WebElement passwordInputField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password'"));
passwordInputField.sendKeys("123456");
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks! Also you can right click on a Element when you are looking at the page source and click copy -> xpath.

Comment: True, with that said generally the XPATH that is generated with right click is not always the most robust one... if the hierarchy of elements change it brakes the XPath... that's why we try to find a more specific XPath with the attributes of that element like `@type='password'`...